# Update ValidationSummary list on control blurs?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, dom-events, validationsummary

A `ValidationSummary` will show a list of errors on postback. As each field is fixed, it's validator is fired, and any validation text will disappear. I want to automatically update the `ValidationSummary` as well.

The following works fine:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ForenameTextBox" onblur="ValidationSummaryOnSubmit()" runat="server" />
```

but this isn't ideal, as it means changing and maintaining this on all fields. (`ValidationSummaryOnSubmit` is a Microsoft function.) So I tried to do it dynamically:

```
addEvent(window, "load", UpdateValidationSummary);

function addEvent(obj, evType, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, true);
    } else {
        if (obj.attachEvent) {
            var r = obj.attachEvent("on" + evType, fn);
            return r;
        }
    }
}

function removeEvent(obj, evType, fn) {
    if (obj.removeEventListener) {
        obj.removeEventListener(evType, fn, true);
        return true;
    } else if (obj.detachEvent) {
        var r = obj.detachEvent("on" + evType, fn);
        return r;
    }
}

function UpdateValidationSummary() {
    if (typeof (Page_Validators) == "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    var i, val, ctrl;
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        val = Page_Validators[i];
        if (val.controltovalidate != null && val.controltovalidate != "") {
            ctrl = document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate);
            if (ctrl != null && typeof (ValidationSummaryOnSubmit) == "function") {
                //add call to ValidationSummary on blur
                addEvent(ctrl, "blur", ValidationSummaryOnSubmit);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work though - the whole `ValidationSummary` disappears when one field is fixed, and the `ValidationSummaryOnSubmit` function seems to get called twice. If I use a simple assignment instead of the `addEvent` function it works, but I want to cater for fields that might already have something going on in the `onBlur` event.

Basically I think I just need to add a call to the `ValidationSummaryOnSubmit` function to the "list" of `onBlur` handlers for each control. Why doesn't the code above seem to do this?

Comment: This is another approach you might find helpful;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610939/asp-net-validationsummary-not-shown-after-onchange-event/10539156#10539156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a server-side approach to get the onblur attribute on all TextBoxes (which should also work with Validation Groups):

- Create a class derived from TextBox, e.g., TextBoxEx
- Add the attribute in this derived class e.g., `this.Attributes.Add("onblur", string.Format("ValidationSummaryOnSubmit('{0}')", this.ValidationGroup);`
- Use tag mapping so that all of your existing `<asp:TextBox>` tags will still work:
  `<system.web>
  <pages>
  <tagMapping>
  <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"
  mappedTagType="MyControls.TextBoxEx"/>
  </tagMapping>
  </pages>
  </system.web>`

Another way would be to use [ControlAdapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx) to add the attribute.

Relevant links:
[Understanding ASP.NET Validation](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/understandingaspnetvalidationlibrary.aspx)
[MSDN - tagMapping Element for pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641.aspx)

Comment: yeah, that's a good idea, thanks. I would like to know why my script doesn't quite work though...

Comment: When I use the first method, simply putting it in the asp control's attributes, I also get the validation message appearing twice. Anyone know what's causing this?