# Validator Summary will not update dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, requiredfieldvalidator, validationsummary

I have a validation Summary I am using for the RequiredFieldValidators to use to show the error messages while an image shows up next to the controls being validated.  I have set the required field validator to Display="Dynamic".  When I select something in the dropdown it removes the image next to the control right away like I want but the errormessage text stays on the ValidatorSummary.

What can I do to make the ValidatorSummary to update dynamically like the RequiredFieldValidator when it removes the image next to the dropdown?

Thanks

Comment: In case somebody else feels like the accepted answer didn't really cover the question (_immediately_ updating the summary), this questions contains a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926527/update-validationsummary-list-on-control-blurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display="Dynamic" isn't what makes the Required Field Validator show up "dynamically".  That setting is for whether the page allocates the space for the field on the page even if it is hidden.  It's more of a page display setting.

Check the "EnableClientScript" property for your Validation Summary.  Set it to true; that is what makes the validators work without having to post back to the server.